# Is there a way to allow a Swift protocol extension to access something in a class that implements said protocol, but which nothing else can access?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

Long-winded question I know. An example is probably simpler:

```
var thing = ThingDoer()
thing.doSomething()

class ThingDoer: DoThings {
    private func sortOfPrivateDoSomething () {}
}

extension DoThings {
    func doSomething () {
        self.sortOfPrivateDoSomething()
    }
}

protocol DoThings {
    func doSomething ()
}
```

`extension DoThings` clearly cannot access `sortOfPrivateDoSomething()`. Is there any way one can add a func - or a computed var, etc. - to `class ThingDoer: DoThings` in such a way that `extension DoThings` could access it, but nothing else could?

*caveat*: `class ThingDoer: DoThings` and `extension DoThings` cannot be in the same file.

Thank you for reading.

---

**Appendix**

I am not sure I would posit the following as *an acceptable answer*, but I feel I should add it, to show the nearest I have managed to get to a solution thus far:

```
var thing = ThingDoer()
thing.doSomething()

class ThingDoer: DoThings {
    fileprivate var someOtherThing: SomeSortOfOtherThing
    init () { someOtherThing = SomeSortOfOtherThing() }
}

extension DoThings {
    fileprivate var _someOtherThing: SomeSortOfOtherThing? {
        let selfReflection = Mirror( reflecting: self )
        for ( _, child ) in selfReflection.children.enumerated() {
            if child.value is SomeSortOfOtherThing { return ( child.value as! SomeSortOfOtherThing ) }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func doSomething () {
        guard var scopedSomeOtherThing = _someOtherThing else { return }
        scopedSomeOtherThing.doSomeOtherThing()
    }
}

protocol DoThings {
    func doSomething ()
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is a simple "no". But worth asking.

Comment: You're correct. The answer is "no."

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your class and protocol extension in the same file, you can use the following code:

```
protocol DoThings {
    func doSomething ()
}

class ThingDoer: DoThings {
    fileprivate func sortOfPrivateDoSomething () {}
}

extension DoThings where Self: ThingDoer {
    func doSomething () {
        sortOfPrivateDoSomething()
    }
}

let thing = ThingDoer()
thing.doSomething()
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander-Gaidukov. I forgot to add that wasn't possible, I'll edit the question now

Comment: In this case, I don't think it is feasible.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed. I'll leave the question open though, in case anyone has any greater wisdom. Thanks anyway @Alexander-Gaidukov

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit from writing something like this in your protocol file

```
extension DoThings where Self: ThingDoer {
    func doSomething () {
        sortOfPrivateDoSomething()
    }
    private func sortOfPrivateDoSomething () {
    }
}
```